Is isoperimetric hypersurface unique up to homeomorphism?
Is there a Riemannian structure on $\mathbb{R}^n $with two non homeomorphic  compact  hypersurfaces $M,N$  such that both satisfy the  isoperimetric  inequality. I  precisely meanthe  following:
$$\ell(M)=\ell(N)=\ell,\;\;   A(M^o)=A(N^o)=A$$
and  for  every compact  hypersurface $P$ with $\ell(P)=\ell$  we  have  $A(P^o)\leq A$
Here $\ell(M)=\int_M vol_M$  the  natural  volum  form  on $M$ naturally  arises from the  volum form on the underling  manifold. $A(M^o)$ is the area of the  bounded component of $M^c$ wrt the  volum form arising from the  metric

Yes, you should be able to construct such a metric. Form "bubbles" on $R^2$ i.e. spheres connected sum with the flat plane to produce a small neck. It's clear that the neck is very good isoperimetrically. Now, make two spheres that contain volume V together, and have total neck area A, and make another single sphere with volume V and area A. You should be able to argue that the isoperimtric problem at this volume V has a solution given by two disks and also one given by one. It may take a bit of work to make this rigorous, but I am pretty sure it can be done by a limit argument..

@OtisChodosh  Thank  you  very much   for  your  attention. I  would  appreciate if you give  a  complete proof.
